# How to put ads on a flex based application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Can you please tell how can we place ADS (whether Google Adsense or others) on a website completely designed in FLEX?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to not have your site COMPLETELY in flex.  Otherwise you can have your flex ap use the AdSense API http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/featuresbenefits.html and make SOAP calls to it.

Other ad servers, like OpenX can also be handled this way (via their API) in flex.  I don't know that any of them support cool stuff like AMF but OpenX is open source and in PHP so you could use the Zend Frameworks support of AMF to add that kind of functionality.